# XSLT version 2.0: Using fn:upper-case for local-name attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am struggling with **xslt 2.0** upper-case method. I saw a lot of examples and it did always look easy. However, I am not able to proceed with my case:

I have a XML (for simplification I changed the names and removed soap tags):

```
<fcl:a>
   <ole:b>
      <yes:c>ThisIsAValue</yes:c>
   </ole:b>
</fcl:a>
```

This works as intended (in XSLT):

```
"Val":"<xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*[local-name()='c']/text()"/>"
```

I receive the value "ThisIsAValue". But if I would like to have it in upper case, I was not able to find a working solution. Does anyone have a proper solution under the condition, to **use local-names**.

What I already tried: fn:upper-case() with namespace to XPath or normal upper-case(). What ever I tried, it did not work. Also not if I first defined a variable and then grabbed this variable and just did:

```
"Val":"<xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case($variable)"/>"
```

Any help would be from great relief. I will not use the translate-function of xslt 1.0.

Comment: Well do you really use an XSLT 2.0 processor? And which result do you want, if the path selects several nodes, do you want to output the string values of all of them, or just of the first? Consider to provide an input sample with all required namespace declarations as otherwise we have no code sample to work with to present an XSLT snippet that works.

Comment: I tried http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfc with your path wrapped into an `upper-case()` call (i.e. `upper-case(//*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*[local-name()='c']/text())`) against a minimal namespace well-formed sample and the output is  `THISISAVALUE`. So please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, together with a precise error message if you get one.

Comment: I am using [utilities-online.info](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/) for testing it and my full stylesheet looks like this:
`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="2.0"><xsl:output method="text"/><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:variable name="variable" select="//*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*[local-name()='c']/text()" />"Val":"<xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case($variable)"/>"</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>` I don't get any error message. But also no text.

Comment: I think the website at utilities-online.info is using an XSLT 1.0 processor, so the upper-case function will not work there. http://xsltransform.net is a much better website to use for testing.

Comment: I agree with Tim's assessment, it looks like you are trying to run XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 1.0 processor like the Xalan implementation included in Java 1.7.

Comment: Your sample at http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYie returns `"Val":"THISISAVALUE"`. So make sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 if you want to use XPath 2.0 functions like `upper-case`.

Comment: That solves it for me. Thanks to @MartinHonnen and to TimC. For future cases I will go with xsltransform.net.

Comment: I could not see where the value of the $variable was set ?!

Comment: <xsl:variable name="variable" select="//*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*[local-name()='c']/text()" />